# Symfony 2 Set Embedded Entity Form Data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, symfony

Currently I have embedded entity forms in a form. And I would like the underlying data to auto populate the address fields when a user selects a project. However using the form events as shown below in the entities and the corresponding ajax code specified in the Symfony 2 documentation, the address fields are never populated in the corresponding ajax response.

Using var_dump I can see that the address is grabbed and sent to the data option when I add the address field. But it never shows up in the form response when the form is submitted with just the selected project.

Is this the proper way to do it or am I missing some vital piece somewhere? Or does symfony not do this and should I do it via jquery/ajax?

**TransactionUser**

```
class TransactionUser
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * The associated transaction to this TransactionUser.
     *
     * @var \Acme\BaseBundle\Entity\Transaction $transaction
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\BaseBundle\Entity\Transaction", inversedBy="transactionUsers", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $transaction;

    /**
     * The Project that this TransactionUser is associated with.
     *
     * @var \Acme\BaseBundle\Entity\Project
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\BaseBundle\Entity\Project", inversedBy="transactionUsers", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $project;
}
```

**Transaction**

```
class Transaction
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Acme\BaseBundle\Entity\Address
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\BaseBundle\Entity\Address", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="propertyAddressTransactions")
     */
    private $propertyAddress;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\BaseBundle\Entity\TransactionUser", mappedBy="transaction", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $transactionUsers;

}
```

**Address**

```
class Address
{
    /**
     * The database id for the Address.
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * The first line of the street address.
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="streetAddressLine1", type="text")
     */
    private $streetAddressLine1;

    /**
     * The Transactions that list this address as the property address.
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\BaseBundle\Entity\Transaction", mappedBy="propertyAddress")
     */
    private $propertyAddressTransactions;
}
```

**Project**

```
class Project
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\BaseBundle\Entity\TransactionUser", mappedBy="project", cascade={"all"})
     * \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    private $transactionUsers;

}
```

**NewTransactionFormType**

```
class NewTransactionFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add('project', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AcmeBaseBundle:Project',
                'required' => false,
                'optional' => true,
                'label' => 'Select Project',
                'placeholder' => 'Select Project',
                'property' => 'projectName',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    $queryBuilder = $er->createQueryBuilder('p');
                    return $queryBuilder;
                },
        ));

        $builder->add('transaction', NewTransactionSubFormType::class);

        $builder->get('transaction')->add('propertyAddress', AddressFormType::class);

        //Listeners on project to set the address
        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Project $project = null) {
            $address = null;

            if (!is_null($project) && !is_null($project->getId())) {
                $address = $project->getFirstTransactionAddress();
            }

            $form->get('transaction')->add('propertyAddress', AddressFormType::class, array(
                'data' => $address
            ));
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // this would be your entity, i.e. Transaction
                $data = $event->getData();

                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getProject());
            }
        );

        $builder->get('project')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
                // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
                $project = $event->getForm()->getData();

                // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
                // the parent to the callback functions!
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $project);
            }
        );

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\BaseBundle\Entity\TransactionUser',
        ));
    }
}
```

**NewTransactionSubFormType**

```
class NewTransactionSubFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Name',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => '',
                'placeholder' => 'Name',
            ),
            'required' => true,
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\BaseBundle\Entity\Transaction',
        ));
    }
}
```

**AddressFormType**

```
class AddressFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('streetAddressLine1', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Street Address Line 1',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => '',
                'placeholder' => 'Street Address Line 1',
            ),
            'required' => true,
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\BaseBundle\Entity\Address',
        ));
    }
}
```